# Not able to verify tor setup for RPC

Tags: json-rpc, tor

I'm currently in chapter 14.1 (verify your tor setup) of the  [learning bitcoin from the command line](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/blob/master/14_1_Verifying_Your_Tor_Setup.md#verify-your-tor-setup) course by blockchaincommons.

I don't get my head around doing the actual RPC verification via torify and I assume my linode-node is not running properly behind tor.
When I type sudo -u debian-tor tor --verify-config everything is fine and I see the expected result.

However when I try to check the rpc ports in /etc/tor/torrc I can NOT see the hidden service ports described in the docs. There it only says:

```
############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###

## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

I can see them in the bitcoin.conf file but that doesn't help much... I have an QR-code but I'm not able to connect with my node through it. And I don't have a `/var/lib/tor/standup/hostname` directory at all.

What I CAN do is verifying my tor-setup for bitcoind running `grep "tor:" ~/.bitcoin/testnet3/debug.log`.

I assume, something went wrong during the initial install. But can anybody tell me, how to fix it?

PS: Explanations for differences between RPC and bitcoind are also welcome, I think I'm not getting that right either...

Comment: At the top of the guide you linked, it mentions setup with Bitcoin StandUp. I can see that the [Linux StandUp script](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Bitcoin-Standup-Scripts/blob/master/Scripts/StandUp.sh) should have set the ports in torrc. Did you use this script?

Comment: Might checkout the [tor guide](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md) in bitcoin-core.  If your using "option 2" then core is making the Tor service for you via the Tor API.

Comment: @meshcollider yes I did us Bitcoin StandUp. Question is, can I simply add them manually in the displayed section above?

Comment: @zerotobtc I think the setup is more complicated than just adding those lines to the file. I'd recommend using the Tor setup guide linked by Dan

Comment: Thanks @Dan for the link to the setup guide, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why the error occurred however I found a workaround.

I added the lines

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/standup/
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 1309 127.0.0.1:18332
HiddenServicePort 1309 127.0.0.1:18443
HiddenServicePort 1309 127.0.0.1:8332
```

in the `/etc/tor/torrc` file (according to the [tor guide](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md)) in the hidden service section. Then I restarted tor with `systemctl restart tor`. Afterwards the `/var/lib/tor/standup/hostname` file was created and also the `torify` command went through just fine!